# Python/MySQL batch UPDATE optimisation

Tags: python, mysql, optimization

I'm currently trying to determine the best means of performing a bulk UPDATE into a MySQL DB, in terms of speed. Unfortunately, each row needs a separate update and I'm basing it off the ID (auto-incremented) of the table. Hence the need for one UPDATE statement per row. The table itself is around 12m records and I probably only need to update around 100,000 per day.

For batch INSERT statements, I am able to use the executemany() function, but unfortunately the same function does not seem to affect UPDATE statements. I have read that this is due to the fact that the optimisations in MySQL which allow this function to work are hardcoded for INSERTS.

Currently I am considering creating a temporary table which will store a key-value pair of ID and update_value which will then be updated into the table requiring an update via an update join. Is this a good idea, considering the database is a master for a chained replication topology?

I am currently using MyISAM as the storage engine for this table as it is read frequently (but not at the same time as the update). Admittedly I have not benchmarked it using InnoDB. I realise that MyISAM has table level locking and that an UPDATE will lock the entire table for the duration of that particular update. If I switch to InnoDB is MySQL smart enough to perform the updates concurrently if provided via executemany() and am I likely to see any speed increase?

Comment: Step 1: Implement the techniques you have.  Step 2: Measure the performance for the techniques you already have.  Step 3: Evaluate the measurements to see if any of them are acceptable (they might be).  Step 4:  Find the bottleneck that prevents performance.  If it's the Python code then, Step 5: Profile the Python code.  Step 6: **Update** the question with the measurements you have and the time that's required.  It's really hard to answer hypothetically, since we don't have your server or your database configuration.

Comment: Thanks - I will do so and report back. However, I am concerned about the temporary table and replication. Are there any issues there? Apologies for deviating a little from the original topic, but I do feel it is relevant to the UPDATE question.

Comment: Temporary tables are often a very bad idea.  A database is slow.  Very slow.  Often the best way to do this kind of update is to create a "replacement" table outside the database:  extract old data, update, and reload new data.  Fussing around with "temporary tables" in the database is usually a sign of a design that should use flat files outside the database.